# Python split string having n dots and get the value from toml

Tags: python, toml

I am having a toml file config.toml

```
path.repo_uat7="/home/developer/user1"
path.repo_uat12="/home/repo/user21"
database.hostname.uat7="dbname7"
database.hostname.uat12="dbname12"
database.port="1825"
db.cluster.nodes=["cluster1:15382","cluster2:15382"]
```

I am reading the above file using python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import toml
import sys
data = toml.load("config.toml")
desc = str(sys.argv[1])
st = desc.split(".")
st1 = st[0]
st2 = st[1]

print(data[st1][st2])
```

If I want value for path.repo_uat7, I am running the code as:

```
python getvar.py path.repo_uat7
```

which is giving the required output **/home/developer/user1**

to get the value of db.cluster.nodes I am runnig code as

```
python getvar.py db.cluster.nodes
```

and I am getting output as: **{'nodes': ['cluster1:15382', 'cluster2:15382']}**
I want the output to be **['cluster1:15382', 'cluster2:15382']**

Is there any way to split the dot separated string, which can be used if it string is having 2 dots, 3 or n? Please help.

Comment: Is it a string? looks more like a dict with the {}. If so, you could try: `python getvar.py db.cluster.nodes['nodes']`

Comment: This gives me the output as {'nodes': ['cluster1:15382', 'cluster2:15382']}

Comment: If I am running python getvar.py database.hostname.uat7['uat7'] , I am getting output as
{'uat7': 'dbname7'}  . I only want output to be dbname7

Comment: Is the output a string or a dict? 
if it is a string you could try: `db.cluster.nodes.split(':')[1:]`. But again, it looks more like a dict. you should figure out the data type you get returned in order to know what to do